# java compile classpath

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I want to code a script to compile and run a java file in the Windows env, but failed. It is failed in the java classpath.

This Test.java is not inside any package.

Please help. Thanks.

```
set SOURCE=C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Desktop
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
"%JAVA_HOME%\javac"  "%SOURCE%\Test.java"
pause

"%JAVA_HOME%\java" -cp "%SOURCE%" Test.class
pause
```

Comment: If you have whitespace in directory name, you should either use a forward slash to escape the name OR put the complete path in quotes. set SOURCE="C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Desktop"

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `.class` extension from the name of the class you pass to the `java` command:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\java" -cp "%SOURCE%" Test
```